# How to access gallery from the camera view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I am looking for way to allow user to access image gallery from the camera view.

By default, one have to explicitly set source type for `UIImagePickerController`

```
self.myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
```

Is there any way to make it in the way like in native ios camera app? Notice the tiny picture in the bottom-left corner

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any option to do that you need to give different source type for both

Answer (score 0):

you can have two options presented to users and allow them to choose photo from Album or take a photo using camera

```html
        if (optionId == 1) {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
                imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, kUTTypeImage, nil];
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
                
                imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
                
                [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
            }else {
                UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Camera not supported."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alertView show];
            }
            
        }else if (optionId == 2) {
            imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            if ( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            } else  {
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            }
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, kUTTypeImage, nil];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
            
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```